# Mutiple Image Upload Using 1 Image TV in MODx Revolution

Tags: php, content-management-system, modx-revolution

I would like to list down images on a resource page and displays as a thumbnails. Now i know there's a TV to upload an image w/c is "Image TV", where you will be able to upload the image and call the TV name on the resource template. But i want to have multiple images displays on a single resource, and this could be dynamic like there will be 4 or more images to be displayed. Is there a way on MODx revolution to upload multiple images using single Image TV? I found out about MIGX but it wont allow upload just type down the image URL.

Answers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the gallery extra and in your tv, point to the gallery id of the set of images you want to display then use the gallery snippet on the front end [passing the tv value to the template] for display.

Comment: can you guide me through it step by step? or if not, can you provide me a link which has a tutorial for that one? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just create TV and set as *RichText*, output *String*.

Next you upload images as list element and in css you need style this list and display TV content in div with uniq id.

For example I have slides with dynamic number of images, and in jQuery I add white frames, shadows etc.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        /*  Images: rotate, frame, shadow  */
        $('.rotation ul li img').each(function() {
            var mleft = 0;
            var mtop = 0;
            if ($(this).is(":first-child")) {
            }
            else {
                mleft = parseInt($(this).prev().attr("width"), 10) + parseInt($(this).prev().css('margin-left'), 10);
                if (parseInt(mleft, 10) + parseInt($(this).attr("width"), 10) > 430) {
                    mleft = 0;
                    mtop = 250 - parseInt($(this).attr("height"), 10);
                }
            }
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) - 8;
            $(this).css({'border': '5px #ffffff solid', 'border-radius':'10px', 'transform': 'rotate(' + rand + 'deg)', '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + rand + 'deg)', '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + rand + 'deg)', '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + rand + 'deg)', 'box-shadow': '4px 4px 10px -3px #000000', 'float': 'left', 'margin': '-30px 0 0 -20px'});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Adding class which I need to rotate images:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.rotation ul').addClass('image_rotation');
        $('.image_rotation').css("display","block");
        $('.image_rotation').innerfade({
            speed: 'slow',
            timeout: 10000,
            type: 'sequence'
        });
    });
</script>
```

html output from TV:

```
    <ul>
        <li><img src="assets/images/4.jpg" alt="" width="210" height="139" /><img src="assets/images/5.jpg" alt="" width="117" height="169" /><img src="assets/images/6.jpg" alt="" width="149" height="114" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/images/2.jpg" alt="" width="184" height="187" /><img src="assets/images/3.jpg" alt="" width="167" height="179" /></li>
        <li><img src="assets/images/1.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="232" /></li>
    </ul>
```

TV

```
<div class="rotation">[[TV]]
</div>
```

So I upload images as list, and each li tag is separate images group to rotate. You can upload as many images as you want.